# pg8000 Can't Parameterize Queries

Tags: python, postgresql, pg8000

I've been trying to use pg8000 to interact with my SQL server, but for some reason, it won't accept params properly. It does seem to recognize the paramstyle, and then knows to change those to the PostgreSQL params, but it never seems to pass the params through. I looked at the documentation example here [(link)](http://pybrary.net/pg8000/interactiveexample.html) for examples, and they didn't work. Here are some examples:

```
query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM schema.table_name
        """
conn = pg8000.connect(**credential_dict)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

This example works. The next two do not:

```
query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM %s
        """
conn = pg8000.connect(**credential_dict)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, 'schema.table_name')

query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM %s
        """
conn = pg8000.connect(**credential_dict)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, ('schema.table_name',))
```

These queries fail, but the error I get says the error is at the `$1` which pg8000 converts the `%s` to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: my guess is that one should pass query parameters which are used on the right side of restrictions like `IN (%s, %s)`, `= %s` and so on, not schema items like table or columns names

Comment: Tried that, and got a different error. Query was `SELECT * FROM schema.table_name WHERE column IN (%s);` and got the error `ProgrammingError: (u'ERROR', u'ERROR', u'25P02', u'current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block', u'postgres.c', u'1309', u'exec_parse_message')`

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM schema.table_name WHERE column = '%s';`

Comment: Same error, but also not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL, some parts of SQL statements [can't be parameterized](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#many-sql-statements-cant-be-parameterized). In your example:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s", 'schema.table_name')
```

the table name can't be parameterized, so you'd have to create the string yourself instead:

```
table_name = 'schema.table_name'
cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try explicitly naming your parameter and passing as a `dict`:

```
param_dict = dict(table_name = 'schema.table_name')
query = """SELECT * FROM %(table_name)s"""
# cursor setup code...
cursor.execute(query, param_dict)
```

Comment: Does not work. If I do this without changing the paramstyle, I get an error from pg8000 saying that this style is incorrect. If I do change the paramstyle to pyformat, I get the same error I initially got.